# Angular JS: can I define two ng-apps on same page and can they communicate with each other?

Tags: angularjs

The reason I am exploring this is because I think that will let me have two ng-views which can be updated independently...  Does this make sense?  Am I thinking about it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can define two apps on same page but manual bootstrapping is required.

Comment: In other words Angular isn't really designed for that and I would have to write my own solution for how they communicate to with each other ?

Comment: Do you have an example or link?